# PDO does not work when trying to login old code works

Tags: php, pdo

I already posted this, but it was incomplete: 
I have a login system which works, but I need to get it working with PDO!
Does anyone know where it goes wrong and what i need to change?
First part of code is the old (working but not PDO)
Second part of code is my try of pdo!

```
<?php
ob_start();


if(isset($_REQUEST['password']))
{

    require 'connect.php';  
    $password =$_REQUEST['password'];
    $mail = $_REQUEST['email'];

    if(empty($mail) || empty($password)){
        header('location: ../login.php?error=empty');
        exit();
    }
    else{

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE email = ?;";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
            header("Location: ../login.php?error=sqlError");
            exit();
        }
        else{

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $mail);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $passwordCheck = password_verify($password, $row['wachtwoord']);
                if($passwordCheck == false ){

                    header("Location: ../login.php?error=passwordWrong");
                    exit();
                }
                else if($passwordCheck == true){
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['account_id'];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['gebruikersnaam'];
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=succes");
                    exit();
                }
            }
            else{

                header("Location: login.php?error=noUser");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }

}
else{
    header("Location: ../login.php?error=fail");
    exit();
}
```

Second part:

```
<?php
ni_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
ob_start();


if(isset($_REQUEST['password']))
{

    require 'connect.php';  
    $password =$_REQUEST['password'];
    $mail = $_REQUEST['email'];

    if(empty($mail) || empty($password)){
        header('location: ../login.php?error=empty');
        exit();
    }
    else{

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE email = ?;";
        $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam('?', $mail);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row_length-> $stmt->fetchColumn();
        $row = $stmt->fetchColumn();
            if($row_length == 1 ){
                $passwordCheck = password_verify($password, $row['wachtwoord']);
                if($passwordCheck == false ){

                    header("Location: ../login.php?error=passwordWrong");
                    exit();
                }
                else if($passwordCheck == true){
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['account_id'];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['gebruikersnaam'];
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=succes");
                    exit();
                }
            }
            else{

                header("Location: login.php?error=noUser");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }


else{
    header("Location: ../login.php?error=fail");
    exit();
}
```

I don't get an error message, just a HTTP error 500

Comment: change `$stmt->bindParam('?', $mail);` to `$stmt->bindParam(1, $mail);`

Comment: _“just a HTTP error 500”_ - then go check the error logs, that is always the first thing you do on a 500.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a 500 error my first suspicion would be this:

```
ni_set('display_errors', 1);
```

I expect this is causing an issue as it should be ini_set